# Selenium how to get text only from <b> tag inside class

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, browser-automation

I am trying to get all product prices from a site into a list using python and selenium, but I am facing a problem when the price is discounted and looks like this on the site:

[image: discounted price]

HTML code for this site:

```html
<span class="product-price promo-price">
  <b>
    79,00
    ::after
  </b>
  <del>
    89,00
    ::after
  </del>
</span>
```

My selenium code for getting prices into list:

```py
def test5():
    sort = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sorter-button").click()
    sort2 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sorter-listing > span:nth-child(3) > label:nth-child(2)").click()
    prices = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "product-price ")
    a = []
    for i in prices:
        a.append(i.text)
    print(a)
```

The output of this code is:

```py
['19,90', '50,00', '78,99', '79,00\n89,00', '95,00\n128,00', '135,00', '137,95', '149,00\n158,00', '191,00', '199,00', '199,99\n267,50', '200,00\n300,00']
```

The problem is getting both discounted and normal values, for example - `79,00\n89,00`

How can I get only discounted prices so list would look like this:

```py
['19,90', '50,00', '78,99', '79,00', '95,00', '135,00', '137,95', '149,00', '191,00', '199,00', '199,99', '200,00']
```

If I do it, for example by `XPATH`, then I can get only one price from site, not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 a.append(i.text.splitlines[1])
```